# Installing Multiple .NET Versions

Tags: wine

I have a Windows application that I am told by the developer requires two different versions of .NET in order to run and when I try to install one of them, there is an error that there is already a later version installed. In Windows, it is not uncommon and even expected to have multiple versions available for the applications that need them so how can that be done in WINE? Can the .NET installation be forced somehow?

Attempting to run the .exe from the command line to see if there are specific errors, it gave this while double-clicing the file from the desktop did nothing whatsoever.

```
don@Dev:~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/ExpressPCBPlus$ wine ExpressPCBPlus.exe
029c:err:module:fixup_imports_ilonly mscoree.dll not found, IL-only binary L"ExpressPCBPlus.exe" cannot be loaded
029c:err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Importing dlls for L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ExpressPCBPlus\\ExpressPCBPlus.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

Comment: Unlikely you will get an answer here. If you have windows software I always would advice to use virtualbox or vmware player and install windows in that and your app in there. 100% guaranteed to work.  If you want to explore the wine path you are better off asking this on WINEHQ forums https://forum.winehq.org/The experts are there.

Comment: If you want to ask about getting a Windows application running on Ubuntu, you should tell us what application you are trying to run and where you obtained it. Windows apps were not designed to run on Ubuntu. Every application is different. There is not a "one size fits all" prescriptive solution to running Windows apps. You'll need to figure out the quirks and obstacles of this particular application, if it runs at all. In order for *us* to help, you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: Thank you and yes, I know that and I didn't mean to imply that I asking about the application itself but whether or not multiple instances of .NET could be installed. That said, the software is ExpressPCBPlus. ExpressPCB runs just fine but the Plus version does not and I got it directly from the developer's site. There are no installation errors but nothing whatsoever happens when it is clicked to open.

Comment: @Nmath I appended my question with some errors when trying to run it from the terminal command line. Maybe they'll help but mscoree.dll is installed already.

Answer (score 0):

> Installing Multiple .NET Versions

That is the default [winetricks](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winetricks) behaviour

```
winetricks dlls list |grep dotnet
```

```
dotnet35sp1              MS .NET 3.5 SP1 (Microsoft, 2008) [downloadable]
dotnet40                 MS .NET 4.0 (Microsoft, 2011) [downloadable,cached]
dotnet40_kb2468871       MS .NET 4.0 KB2468871 (Microsoft, 2011) [downloadable]
dotnet45                 MS .NET 4.5 (Microsoft, 2012) [downloadable,cached]
dotnet452                MS .NET 4.5.2 (Microsoft, 2012) [downloadable,cached]
dotnet46                 MS .NET 4.6 (Microsoft, 2015) [downloadable,cached]
dotnet461                MS .NET 4.6.1 (Microsoft, 2015) [downloadable,cached]
dotnet462                MS .NET 4.6.2 (Microsoft, 2016) [downloadable]
dotnet471                MS .NET 4.7.1 (Microsoft, 2017) [downloadable]
dotnet472                MS .NET 4.7.2 (Microsoft, 2018) [downloadable]
dotnet48                 MS .NET 4.8 (Microsoft, 2019) [downloadable,cached]
dotnet_verifier          MS .NET Verifier (Microsoft, 2016) [downloadable]
dotnetcore2              MS .NET Core Runtime 2.1 LTS (Microsoft, 2020) [downloadable]
dotnetcore3              MS .NET Core Runtime 3.1 LTS (Microsoft, 2020) [downloadable,cached]
dotnetcoredesktop3       MS .NET Core Desktop Runtime 3.1 LTS (Microsoft, 2020) [downloadable]
vjrun20                  MS Visual J# 2.0 SE libraries (requires dotnet20) (Microsoft, 2007) [downloadable]
```

if you ask winetricks to install .Net 4.5 it will install net4 then net 4.5

```bash
# rm -rf $PWD/pfx1 && mkdir -p $PWD/pfx1 # brand new prefix
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=$PWD/pfx1  winetricks dotnet452
```

Currently wine dotnet4 verb is win32 only

try it on a brand new prefix

Winetricks will remove mono

If you do it by hand you have to remove mono your self

```
wine uninstaller # remove mono from  there if its listed
```